Partial respond in aspnet core controller
I'm creating a web api that search throw all tables of the database and it require severl minutes to finish.
Is there a way to create a method that return a partial results whitout terminating the search process?
like for example:
public async IAsyncEnumerable<List<DataRow>> DbSearch(...parameters) {

   ...
   foreach(var row in schemaDatabase.Rows) {
      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... FROM " + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + " WHERE ...");
      DataTable result = DataTable.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())

      listResult.AddRange(result.Rows);

      // partial result..
      return result.Rows;
   }

   // total result
   return listResult;
}


When you are saying partial result what you are exactly want to return?

I think you might be talking about streaming.
like for example:
public async IAsyncEnumerable<List<DataRow>> DbSearch(...parameters)
{
    ...
    foreach (var row in schemaDatabase.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... FROM " + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + " WHERE ...");
        DataTable result = DataTable.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader());

        yield return result.Rows;
    }
}


there's no point in streaming if you're going to use DataTable.Load which is buffered; this would be better done with, for example, Dapper's .Query<T> using buffered: false for true streaming

maybe he just needs the yield return usage
